No valid biosphere flows found. No inventory results can be calculated, `lcia` will raise an error
I have modeled a simple product system by creating nodes and edges of activities from ecoinvent like this:
# fetching EI activities of interest
code_El_PT = ei_db.search("market for electricity, medium voltage PT")[0]["code"]
act_El_PT = ei_db.get(code_El_PT)
code_calcium_nitrate = ei_db.search("calcium nitrate production RER")[0]['code']
act_calcium_nitrate = ei_db.get(code_calcium_nitrate)

# reference flow / assembly
data = {  
    'code': 'PS_main',
    'name': 'PS_main',
    'location': 'DK',
    'unit': 'PS_main'
}
PS_main = db.new_node(**data)
PS_main.save()

# create nodes
el_data = {
    'code': act_El_PT['code'],
    'name': act_El_PT['name'],
    'location': act_El_PT.get('location', ''),  # Handle potential missing location
    'unit': act_El_PT.get('unit', '')  # Handle potential missing unit
}
el = db.new_node(**el_data)
el.save()

calcium_nitrate_data = {
    'code': act_calcium_nitrate['code'],
    'name': act_calcium_nitrate['name'],
    'location': act_calcium_nitrate.get('location', ''),  # Handle potential missing location
    'unit': act_calcium_nitrate.get('unit', '')  # Handle potential missing unit
}
calcium_nitrate = db.new_node(**calcium_nitrate_data)
calcium_nitrate.save()

## Create edges
PS_main.new_edge(
    amount=2.5, 
    type='technosphere',
    input=el
).save()
PS_main.new_edge(
    amount=2.5, 
    type='technosphere',
    input=calcium_nitrate
).save()

And then tried to perform the LCA calculations like this:
## LCA
gw_method = ('EF v3.1', 'climate change', 'global warming potential (GWP100)')
lca = bc.LCA(demand={PS_main: 1}, method=gw_method)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.score

But got the traceback "EmptyBiosphere" Why is that so? How Which part of my code is wrong?
Yes, The biosphere3 DB is loaded in my project.
Databases dictionary with 3 object(s):
SPS01
biosphere3
ecoinvent 3.10_cutoff_ecoSpold02


The error tells you exactly what the problem is.
class EmptyBiosphere(BW2CalcError):
    """Can't do impact assessment with no biosphere flows"""

    pass

I think this is because of you are recreating nodes without adding the exchanges of these nodes.
for example here:
# create nodes
el_data = {
    'code': act_El_PT['code'],
    'name': act_El_PT['name'],
    'location': act_El_PT.get('location', ''),  # Handle potential missing location
    'unit': act_El_PT.get('unit', '')  # Handle potential missing unit
}
el = db.new_node(**el_data)
el.save()

your recreating the market for electricity, medium voltage PT activity in your what assume is a new db, without any exchanges.
why recreate it when you can just use it.
by adding it directly
PS_main.new_edge(input=act_El_PT.key, amount=XX, type='technosphere')
